# org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins maven repository bundle not available

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, p2

I have been working on integrating the Equinox P2's dropins capability to WSO2 Carbon kernel. For this purpose, I am using the org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins bundle of https://github.com/eclipse/rt.equinox.p2 and I found a Maven dependency for this bundle from Maven repository [link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.adedayo.eclipse.sdk/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins/1.1.300).

But when I investigated the jar downloaded I discovered that it only possessed a META-INF folder and the MANIFEST.MF content contained hardly any of OSGi bundle manifest headers.

Is there an official org.eclipse or any other maven repository bundle dependency available for this module or is this bundle's functionality deprecated as some resources indicate?